# How to colonize Ansible inventories in yaml format

Tags: ansible, yaml

I got this task to convert Ansible inventories from ini to yml, so I take the working ini file and make the usual rounds:
- Github: check - solution hangs
- Online tool: check - solution does not resemble anything from this planet
- Last resort: I read [the official guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html) that brings the following example:

```
all: # keys must be unique, i.e. only one 'hosts' per group
   hosts:
       test1:
       test2:
           var1: value1
   vars:
       group_var1: value2
   children:   # key order does not matter, indentation does
       other_group:
           children:
               group_x:
                   hosts:
                       test5
```

Cool, I quickly turn my original ini to this beauty

ORIGINAL

```
[thingiebob_master]
thng-esxi96

[thingiebob_slaves]
thng-esxi97
```

CONVERTED v1

```
all:
   children:
        thingiebob_master:
            hosts: thng-esxi96
        thingiebob_slaves:
            hosts:
                thng-esxi97
```

I can run a ping and it reaches both machines. But when I add another node to the second group:
CONVERTED v2

```
all:
   children:
        thingiebob_master:
            hosts: thng-esxi96
        thingiebob_slaves:
            hosts:
                thng-esxi97
                thng-esxi98
```

I get an error:

```
PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
fatal: [thng-esxi97 thng-esxi98]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: 
Could not resolve hostname thng-esxi97 thng-esxi98: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

But if I put a colon after them, effectively turning them into keys, as in v3 below, all three nodes are found and pinged.
CONVERTED v3

```
    all:
       children:
            thingiebob_master:
                hosts: thng-esxi96
            thingiebob_slaves:
                hosts:
                    thng-esxi97:
                    thng-esxi98:
```

Result

```
PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************
ok: [thng-esxi98]
ok: [thng-esxi96]
ok: [thng-esxi97]

TASK [ping] *************************************************************************************
ok: [thng-esxi97]
ok: [thng-esxi96]
ok: [thng-esxi98]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
thng-esxi96               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
thng-esxi97               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
thng-esxi98               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Question: (How) Can I add multiple nodes to my thingiebob_slaves group? (Without colonizing them.)

Answer (score 1):

Entertaining question :)

Got this completely wrong on the first pass :( I presumed that a YAML version of the basic INI file mirrored the layout of the data structure used when writing a dynamic inventory script and therefore groups contained lists of hosts. It doesn't and they don't.

I happened to be reading [the Inventory docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) today. This clearly shows that in a YAML version of the basic INI inventory, that a group is indeed a dictionary, containing keys of hostnames and values of either an empty dictionary, or a dictionary of host specific options.

Example from the docs:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mail.example.com:
        ansible_port: 5555
        ansible_host: 192.0.2.50
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
        bar.example.com:
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        one.example.com:
        two.example.com:
        three.example.com:
```

Long story short, you are stuck with the colons.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a more aesthetically pleasing way to do it, but hey... If this is the way it is, this is the way I like it.